# Python regex ignoring pattern

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I have a list of two keywords like below:

```
keywords = ["Azure", "Azure cloud"]
```

but python unable to find the second keyword "Azure cloud"

```
>>> keywords = ["Azure", "Azure cloud"]
>>> r = re.compile('|'.join([re.escape(w) for w in keywords]), flags=re.I)
>>> word = "Azure and Azure cloud"
>>> r.findall(word)
['Azure', 'Azure']
```

I am expecting the output like this : ['Azure', 'Azure', 'Azure cloud']

Any guide/help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Expecting output: ['Azure', 'Azure', 'Azure cloud'] OR ['Azure', 'Azure cloud'] ?

Comment: this : ['Azure', 'Azure', 'Azure cloud']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run multiple search.

```py
import itertools
import re

keywords = ["Azure", "Azure cloud"]
patterns = [re.compile(re.escape(w), flags=re.I) for w in keywords]
word = "Azure and Azure cloud"
results = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    r.findall(word) for r in patterns
))
print(results)
```

output:

```py
['Azure', 'Azure', 'Azure cloud']
```

---

## Append

> if I'd have word = "Azure and azure cloud" - I will have the output as ['Azure', 'azure', 'azure cloud'] - so the 2nd keyword "azure" which is in small, if i would have to get the exact word matching with the "keywords" list which is "Azure", what modification has to be made in the code?

The flag `re.I` means ignore-case. So simply remove this.

```py
patterns = [re.compile(re.escape(w)) for w in keywords]
```

---

## Append 2

> sorry my last comment was vague, so I want the pattern matching to ignore the case, but while fetching the output I would want the keywords to have exact case what we have in the "keyword" list and not in the "word"

Sorry for misunderstanding. Try this:

```py
import re

keywords = ["Azure", "azure cloud"]
patterns = [re.compile(w, flags=re.I) for w in keywords]
word = "Azure and azure cloud"
results = [
    match_obj.re.pattern
    for r in patterns
    for match_obj in r.finditer(word)
]
print(results)
```

output:

```py
['Azure', 'Azure', 'azure cloud']
```

I'm not sure it is effecient way, but it works.
Note that I remove re.escape because it cause space escape so result was:

```py
['Azure', 'Azure', 'azure\\ cloud']
```

Comment: much thanks @Boseong, if I'd have word = "Azure and azure cloud" - I will have the output as ['Azure', 'azure', 'azure cloud'] - so the 2nd keyword "azure" which is in small, if i would have to get the exact word matching with the "keywords" list which is "Azure", what modification has to be made in the code?

Comment: sorry my last comment was vague, so I want the pattern matching to ignore the case, but while fetching the output I would want the keywords to have exact case what we have in the "keyword" list and not in the "word"

Answer (score 2):

`findall` finds all *non-overlapping matches*. And in case of alternations it tries the various cases *left-to-right*.

So what happens here is that the regex engine reaches `Azure cloud`, manages to match `Azure` and... starts looking for it again in `cloud`, since it's managed to match `Azure` to something.

If you expect "Azure and Azure cloud" to yield "Azure", "Azure" *and* "Azure Cloud" you need to run each pattern individually, not a single alternating pattern.